# Delphi TShiftState in Vcl.Controls and System.Classes

Tags: delphi

I am writing a new component for my application which uses the mouse events and the key events. Both the mouse and key events require the parameter type TShiftState, although once i introduce the key event declarations I recieve the error 'E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'' for each of the three methods below.

Declaration code is below:

```
TOnKeyDownEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState) of object;
TOnKeyPressEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Key : Char) of object;
TOnKeyUpEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState) of object;

FOnKeyDownEvent     : TOnKeyDownEvent;
FOnKeyPressEvent    : TOnKeyPressEvent;
FOnKeyUpEvent       : TOnKeyUpEvent;

property OnKeyDownEvent     : TOnKeyDownEvent     read FOnKeyDownEvent write FOnKeyDownEvent;
property OnKeyPressEvent    : TOnKeyPressEvent    read FOnKeyPressEvent write FOnKeyPressEvent;
property OnKeyUpEvent       : TOnKeyUpEvent       read FOnKeyUpEvent write FOnKeyUpEvent;


procedure KeyDown(Sender: TObject; Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState);
procedure KeyPress(Sender: TObject; Key : Char);
procedure KeyUp(Sender: TObject; Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState);
```

Error causing code is below:

```
Self.OnKeyDown := Self.KeyDown;
Self.OnKeyPress := Self.KeyPress;
Self.OnKeyUp := Self.KeyUp;
```

Can anyone tell me why the above code is not working?

Comment: What is `Self` in the context of the code that you've shown ? Also, what is the ancestor of your component ? It looks to me that you're redeclaring what is already done...

Comment: @James_Hill where did you declare that KeyDown procedure. if it is out of the class declaration then it is obvious that you get such error. because FOnKeyDownEvent is a type of TOnKeyDownEvent that needed to be declared in an object (see `of object` in front of the TOnKeyDown declaration). I think you may declare that KeyDown procedure globally in your unit. and I agree with TLama. what is your ancestor?

Comment: Please provide SSCCE. The code in the question is fine. Please try to present code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: TLama: The code is correctly formatted, I just extracted the relevant parts. The first chunk of code, other than the object procedures are types, the rest is contained within an object. The second chunk is in the constructor. Loghman: same as above. All: @jpfollenius has the answer to this question, it was a foolish mistake on my behalf.

Comment: Regarding the accepted answer, code in the question is bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that the `Key` parameters has to be a `var` parameter in order to match the signature of `TKeyEvent` which I guess you are trying to assign this to:

```
procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState) of object;
```

That is because the event handler can change the key code.

Comment: I cannot understand how this can be the answer to the question you asked. @James, where in the question is there a var param?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question was trying to figure out why the error 'E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'' was occurring. I thought it was down to TShiftState existing in Classes and Controls, but it was because the parameter 'Key : Word' should have been 'var Key : Word'. I quickly ruled out parameter list differences as when hovering over the word in the IDE it stated the parameter lists were the same EXCEPT from the class which owned TShiftState. In my code declaration it said it was declared in System.Classes, in the inherited object it said it was from VCL.Controls.

Comment: There is no `var` parameter in the code in the question. So how can either side of the assignment operator either have a `var` param, or expect a `var` param. The event type has no `var` param. The method you assign to the event has no `var` param. Clearly the information in the question is wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the problem is that we don't know what `Self` referes to (note that the property used is called `OnKeyDown` and not `OnKeyDownEvent` as above), so I just guessed because I remember myself getting the signature wrong and dealing with that error.

Comment: Clearly the code in the question is not the code that is running. My gripe is with the asker who posts bogus code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compile for the reason that the compiler states. The type of the value on the right hand side of the assignment does not match the type of the property on the left hand side, specifically because the parameter lists differ.

As presented in the question, there is no obvious reason for that. The parameter lists do indeed match. The only possible explanation is that the types that you use in the parameter lists have the same name but are different types.

This is possible if the multiple types are declared with the same name in different units. You will resolve the problem by either reordering your `uses` clause to ensure that all the code refers to the same types. Or by explicitly specifying the type by giving its full name in the form `UnitName.TypeName`.

The other plausible explanation is that the facts are not as stated in the question. For instance, perhaps `Self.KeyDown` refers to the method `TWinControl.KeyDown` rather than your method.

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this the wrong way.  DO NOT have the component assign handlers to its own events at all.  There are existing `Key(Down/Up/Press)` methods exposed by `TWinControl` that you should be overriding instead, and existing `OnKey(Down/Up/Press)` events that you can promote to `published` if they are not already.  Do not define your own methods and events, use the native ones, eg:

```
type
  TMyComp = class(...)
  protected
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
  published
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnKeyUp;
    property OnKeyPress;
  end;

procedure TMyComp.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  ...
  inherited; // trigger the native OnKeyDown event
end;

procedure TMyComp.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  ...
  inherited; // trigger the native OnKeyUp event
end;

procedure TMyComp.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  ...
  inherited; // trigger the native OnKeyPress event
end;
```

Mouse events work in a similar manner.

Comment: This assumes that the control derives from TWinControl

Comment: I am creating a set of new events also with the component I am making so even though it is a bit more code, I want to construct all events in a similar manner. I was aware mouse events and key events can be done through overriding, however new events I create cannot be done in this manner. If there is a strong reason for using the overriding method of doing things then I will consider changing my approach, but regarding readability and consistency I wanted to do it this way since there are going to be plenty of events that need writing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: non-windowed controls cannot receive keyboard input. So yes, the assumption is that the component is a `TWinControl` descendant.

Comment: @James_Hill: that does not negate what I said in my answer. For processing user input, use the overrides. That is what they are there for. For creating new custom event, you still do not make the component assign handlers to its own events, that prevents anyone else from assigning handlers, and it is redundant anyway. If you are having trouble implementing a custom event, you need to ask a new question and provide those details.